# Xelatex: Accent and macrons on capital letters. Multiple accents on a single letter?

Tags: xetex, symbols, characters, accents

I have trouble getting capital letters with a combination of accent and macron in XeLaTeX. I used this: `\'{\=A}`, but I didn't get the accent where I expected it to be. Also, i was wondering if it is possible to to have an upper case stressed capital letter?

Comment: I didn't understand your question the first time, I've edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the font has the necessary glyphs, you cand use combining accents:

> U+0304 COMBINING MACRON
>   U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE

Thus

```
A^^^^0304^^^^0301
```

or the direct input

```
Ā́
```

(find out how your keyboard can realize it) should produce the requested result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
A^^^^0304^^^^0301

Ā́
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, and to have the capital letter superscript (that's what I meant by "upper case stressed capital letter", sorry for my English), I found out I need this command \textsuperscript{LÚ}.I have a last question, which is quite specific: does any of you know if it possible to get a capital letter with a macron and an accent in italic characters? I got a weird result when I used the regular italic command.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `covington` package :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{covington}
\begin{document}
   \acm{A}
\end{document}
```

You can consult [its manual from here](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/covington/covington.pdf).

[image]

To combine any 2 accents one can use the `\twoacc` function, for example :

```
\twoacc[\~|\={a}]
```

will provide with

[image]

**EDIT**

About the stressed capital letter, since I really don't know about the meaning of it (and to avoid explaining anything I don't understand) : you might want to check the `\textsecstress` function.

Comment: ben was asking about "letters with a combination of accent and macron" and not about a letter accented in the simple way.

Comment: @JeanBaldraque oops... I didn't get the idea the firs time. I've edited my answer.